# Figuring out when $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is increasing and decreasing

Tags: functions, inequality, derivatives

Regarding the function $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$, I'm supposed to figure out when it is increasing/decreasing.

So far, I've found the derivative to be $f'(x) = 2x\cos(x^2)$.

So long as I can solve the inequality $\cos(x^2) > 0$ I can figure the rest out, but this is where I'm stuck.

I've narrowed it down to $-\frac\pi2 < x^2 < \frac\pi2$ meaning $x^2 < \frac\pi2 \pm n2\pi, \ \ n\in \mathbb N$

Then I get $x < \pm \sqrt{\frac\pi2 \pm n2\pi}$

Am I on the right track here? I can't seem to find a path from here.

Comment: For positive $x$, can read off the answer from a picture of $y=\sin t$, no derivative needed.

Comment: Well, first of all, $x^2\geq 0$ for all $x$, so it's not clear why you want it to be negative. What you really have is that $$2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2} < x^2 < 2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}$$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

The "points that matter" in partitioning the increasing/decreasing intervals are the points for which $f'(x) = 0$.  This happens when either $2x = 0$ or $\cos(x^2) = 0$.

The function is increasing when $f'(x) > 0$, and decreasing when $f'(x) < 0$.

Consider each part of the derivative separately.

The linear part of the derivative, $2x$, is positive when $x > 0$, and negative when $x < 0$.

The cosine function part of the derivative, $\cos(x^2)$, is positive when its argument is on one the open intervals

$$(2 \pi n - \pi / 2, 2 \pi n + \pi / 2), n \in \mathbb{Z},$$

and negative when it's on one the open intervals

$$(2 \pi n + \pi / 2, 2 \pi n + 3\pi / 2), n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

The next steps would involve looking at when the product of these two parts changes sign.  Those points would define your increasing/decreasing intervals.

Comment: So by taking the sqrt on both (well, all three) sides, I'd get $\sqrt{2\pi n - \pi/2} < x < \sqrt{2\pi n + \pi /2}$. I'm hitting a dead end again. I'm not clear on how to figure out when the product changes sign.

Comment: Try drawing a number line.  Mark out a few of the intervals.  Going from $-12 \pi$ to $+12 \pi$ should be enough to see the pattern.  Mark each interval with two signs: one for the $2x$ part, and the other for the $\cos(x^2)$ part.  When the signs are the same, the product is positive; when they're different, it's negative.  The trick is handling $x=0$, because that point is in the middle of one of the $\cos$ intervals.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it. I started noting individual intervals on which $f$ increased and decreased and trying to formulate it, I wrote that $f$ increased on intervals $(\sqrt{\frac\pi2 + 2k\pi},\sqrt{\frac\pi2+(2k+1)\pi})$ and decreased on intervals $(\sqrt{\frac\pi2+(2k-1)\pi},\sqrt{\frac\pi2+2k\pi})$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. Does this seem right?